# Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property indexOf. Maybe .load() jquery issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I am getting this error after I cycle through and click around on the page a few times.

The Obj function  below sets a property value in a object coming from a handlebars template input and then loads the next handlebar template question. I can do this and it works fine. The issue is when the redo function gets called.

I call redo to load back one of the previously answer questions and set the value in the previously answered input to the proper value from the object. But then when I proceed to hit submit and call Obj again, should the user change a value of a previously answered question, this error pops in the console and the Obj function doesn't run while redo can continously run over different questions and append previously answered templates.

I should note that before I started putting in the previously answered value from using redo, and just used redo to reload the blank question, everything worked fine.

Hopefully I explained everything well.

Right below in order is a a hbs template that can get rendered, the Obj function, and redo function.

```
<div class="question animated slideInUp">
    <h2>Enter Your Estimated Yearly Income</h2>
    <form onsubmit="Obj(this.income.name,this.income.value)">
        <input min=1 type="number" id="p" name="income" value="" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
</div>








function Obj(name, vale) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents pg refresh
    console.log('hit')
    **$('.form').load(quest[iterator]);   //THIS IS APP.JS:61**
    //loads next html question to page
    if (name) {
        if (name === "state") {
            vale = usStates[stateConvert(vale)];
            //if its the state, we convert the state name to abbrievation
        }
        data[name] = vale;
        //change or set object value
        console.log(data);
    }
    if (iterator >= 1) {
        $('p.enter').next().addClass('enter');
    }
    iterator++; //move array accessor up to next question
}
var data = {};

function stateConvert(value) {
    return value.split(" ").join('_').toString();
    //eliminates spaces in state names to match data
};
//user can click already submitted values to load that original question and change it/
function redo(q, id) {
    q = Number(q);
    //if the current queston on the page is not the one being clicked we then change it to the one being clicked
    if (q + 1 != iterator) {
        iterator++;
        $('.form').load(quest[q], function () {
            $('#p').val(data.income);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wheres the code that sets quest? The error looks like the quest object is being set to null then you trying to get the array off it and its then throwing a null object due to that.

Comment: This was the issue. Why couldn't I detect this! In redo function I always do iterator++, but really what should be happening is the iterator should be q+1 because thats the next form that needs to be loaded. I tested this out and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
function redo(q, id) {
q = Number(q);
//if the current queston on the page is not the one being clicked we then change it to the one being clicked
if (q + 1 != iterator) {

    $('.form').load(quest[q], function () {
        $('#p').val(data.income);
    });
    iterator=q+1;
};
```

};

In my previous code i was always doing iterator++ which caused the iterator to be greater than the lenght of my quest array. What need to be done was set the iterator = q+1 in the redo function as shown above so that on click the next form loaded is the one after the current form being shown.

Thank you to Jaie above!